# Hide an HTML form field when a button is clicked and replace it with a different field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form that has a field that needs to become hidden and replaced with another when a button is clicked.  I can't get rid of this field altogether because its value still must be submitted.  Here is some sample code for reference:

```
<select id="Id.0" onChange="changeTextBox();">
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" onclick="addQual();"/>
```

Basically what needs to happen is when the addButton is clicked, Id.0 must disappear (but remain a member of the form) and be replaced by an identical field with id="Id.1" then upon clicking again id="Id.2" and so on.

Is there a way, using JavaScript or jQuery, to hide and replace this field upon clicking this button? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your coding attempt?

Comment: @BradM I have no code, I did some research but couldn't find a viable solution.  I'm not entirely sure what exactly I should be looking for

Comment: I suggest reading a basic tutorial on javascript, then a tutorial on jQuery.

Comment: The thing @BradM wants to say is: It is most definitely possible and it's one of the easier things to do. As you are a newbie I'd suggest to start with jQuery as you will get quicker results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This with jQuery might help.

```
elmCount = 0;

function addQual()
{
  $("#Id." + elmCount).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $("#Id." + elmCount).css('height', '0px');
  elmCount += 1;
}
```

Thanks to comments.

Comment: When a element is hidden, it won't be posted.  You should add it again with `serialize()`.

Comment: If you only set the visibility to "hidden" it should be submitted anyways. You might want to set the height to 0 as well, though to not mess up your layout

Comment: @MahanGM: jQuery's hide function does exactly the same as *.css('display', 'none'), so your change does not adress the underlying problem. Remove the display: none and use visibility: hidden and height : 0 instead.

Comment: i think an element that is hidden is posted too.. but if it has display:none, then it wont. need to be verified though.. plus, if you have a wrapper on an input, for example, <div style="display: none"><input name="test" type="text" /></div>, test will be posted unless you put the display:none on the input element itself.. (needs to be verified too)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divAny">
 <select id="Id.0" onChange="changeTextBox();">
</div>
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" onclick="addQual();"/>

var index = 0;
function addQual(){
 $("#divAny").hide();
 $("#Id."+index).attr("id" , "Id."+ (++index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @MahanGM's answer, I would minimise the use of jQuery here and do only the following in your `addQual` function:

```
addQual = function() {
    $('select').toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

You then need a css class `hidden` to hide the required element. As others have said, you must not use `display: none` if you don't want to lose the value of the input.

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

And you start out in your markup with both `select`s present, only the one you initially want hidden has the appropriate class:

```
<select id="Id.0">
<select id="Id.1" class="hidden">
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" onclick="addQual();"/>
```

A basic example with `span`s: http://jsfiddle.net/5Dayf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution in my eyes: see here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Efwa5/5/)

HTML, nothing special:

```
<select class="replaceableSelect" id="Id.0">
    <option name="one" value="one">One</option>
</select>
<button id="addButton">Add</button>
```

Javascript using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var changeTextBox = function () {
        /** Your code goes here */
    };

    // add the onchange event to all selects (for the current one and future ones)
    $(document).on("click", "select.replaceableSelect", changeTextBox);

    var currentId = 0,
        currentSelect = $("#Id\\.0");
    $("#addButton").on("click", function (e) {
        // hide the old select
        currentSelect.addClass("invisible");
        // create the new select with increased id and add onchange event
        currentSelect = $('<select class="replaceableSelect" id="Id.' + (++currentId) + '"><option name="two" value="two">Two</option></select>').insertAfter(currentSelect).bind("change", changeTextBox);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.invisible{
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Hint: To process the results of your form, please make sure, every select gets a unique name.